# What does the prankster say in Jaws, through a mouthful of water?

Tags: dialogue, jaws

In the 1975 movie "Jaws", a scene in which two kids pretend to be a shark, by snorkling beneath a "cardboard fin", ends with them being discovered and surrounded by men in boats with rifles.

At this point, one of the two children points to the other and says:

- "*He made me do it! He ...*" (... WHAT DOES HE SAY HERE?)

I'm trying to find out what that kid says at this point.

Comment: I think that he just repeats the line of "He made me do it"

Comment: No help in the script; *One youngster looks up and is greeted by: YOUNGSTER'S POINT OF VIEW Twenty rifles and shotguns pointed directly at him. Surrounding him on three sides. Some of the policemen start to
 lower their guns -- struck dumb. CLOSE - YOUNGSTER  his only defense, he begins to cry -- and feebly raises his hands in unconditional surrender.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

He says

> "He made me do it. He talked me into it."

Here is the clip:
https://getyarn.io/yarn-clip/f78c8cab-2797-4998-a744-46a09762e139

Comment: To me it sounds like, "He made me do it; he told me to do it."

Comment: Just watched the scene on YouTube.  Definitely "He talked me into it."

Comment: Can you believe I've seen that movie in the region of 300 times and still couldn't figure it out? That's it. My life is sorted now. I can sleep again.